# Firebase tracking framework

Tags: swift, frameworks, firebase-analytics

I have designed a framework in Swift and it will be distributed to different clients.

Now I want to have analytic tracking done on this framework (e.g. views from said framework being displayed to user), and I'm considering Firebase Analytics to do the job. Specifically, I want the analytic data to be sent to my Firebase project regardless who uses it.

The problem is, I guarantee one of my clients would also use Firebase Analytic in their app. From my understanding/research, Firebase might not be able to do it.

How could this be done with Firebase? I've checked Stackoverflow for this topic but nothing really answers this scenario. The closest answer out there is this one: [Include Firebase Analytics in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790977/include-firebase-analytics-in-library), but it's for Android and does not provide much detail.

Comment: What you want to do is not a supported scenario. Firebase is for app-level analytics, not for libraries. While you can use Firebase Analytics in your library, they will be reported to the project that is configured for the app.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the input. In your opinion, what product and how could this scenario be achieved?

Comment: Technology recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow. But honestly: I also don't know.